Partial fraction decomposition for $\frac{1}{(z^2+\pi^2)^2}$?
How can I compute partial fraction decomp for $\frac{1}{(z^2+\pi^2)^2}$? I, for some reason, am not able to do it. Here's what I tried:
$$\frac{1}{(z^2+\pi^2)^2} = \frac{1}{(z+i\pi)^2(z-i\pi)^2} = \frac{A}{z+i\pi} + \frac{B}{(z+i\pi)^2} + \frac{C}{z-i\pi} + \frac{D}{(z-i\pi)^2} \iff \\ \iff 1=A(z+i\pi)(z-i\pi)^2 + B(z-i\pi)^2 + C(z+i\pi)^2(z-i\pi) + D(z+i\pi)^2$$
This must be true for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ so  I start supplying values:
$$z=-i\pi: 1 =-4\pi^2B\Rightarrow B = \frac{-1}{4\pi^2} \\ z = +i\pi:1 = -4\pi^2D \Rightarrow D=\frac{-1}{4\pi^2} \\ z = 0: 1=Ai\pi(-1)\pi^2+B(-1)\pi^2+C(-1)\pi^2(-1)i\pi+D(-1)\pi^2 \Rightarrow 1 = -\pi^2B-\pi^2D$$
This is obviously a contradiction, and I am unable to see my mistake. Any help is much appreciated!

Why did you drop $A$ and $C$ in the last conclusion? These coefficients need not be real!

Indeed, I just realized this now that you mentioned it. Thank you for bothering with my simple mistake!

You correctly determined $B=D= -1/(4 \pi^2)$, but the last conclusion is wrong: The “contradiction” comes from the (wrong) assumption that $A$ and $C$ are real numbers.
One can expand the right-hand side of
$$
 1=A(z+i\pi)(z-i\pi)^2 + B(z-i\pi)^2 + C(z+i\pi)^2(z-i\pi) + D(z+i\pi)^2
$$
and solve for the unknowns $A, B, C, D$.
Another option – since $B$ and $D$ are already known – is to subtract the known terms from the left-hand side and determine the partial fraction decomposition of the remainder:
$$
 \frac{1}{(z^2 + \pi^2)^2} - \frac{B}{(z+i \pi)^2}- \frac{D}{(z-i \pi)^2}
 = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2 (z^2+\pi^2)} = \frac{i}{4\pi^3} \left( \frac{1}{z + i \pi}-\frac{1}{z - i \pi}\right)
$$
so that $A=i/(4 \pi^3)$ and $C=-i/(4 \pi^3)$.
